# How to change AS3 Youtube Player to german labeling?

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube-api

How can I change the language of an embedded Flash Youtube video player (AS3) to German? Do I have to do some changes with the URL http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3  ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to force the language on the player.  The player attempts to pick the best language off you your settings on www.youtube.com.

For the AS3 player the language preferences will only activate once video playback has started.

If you use the iframe embed (which is recommended) your language preferences will be applied at impression in the video cued state.